# How to store a request from AWS API Gateway in dynamodb and then send it to an endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, http-proxy

I need to setup a proxy apigateway in AWS that gets requests from the internet, stores the body (and headers) in a dynamodb and then forwards it to another external API gateway. Obviously, I need to wait for the response from the external API gateway and then send it back to the original client.

One possible solution is setting up a Lambda function as apigateway backend integration. This Lambda function stores the request in dynamodb and then simply makes a http call to the other external API Gateway. The problem I now have is that this lambda function is active while waiting for the response from the external API Gateway. This could take up several seconds and therefore is not a viable solution for high traffic environments, since hundreds of lambda functions are active for several seconds at all times. This quickly becomes too expensive.

AWS API Gateway also supports to simply proxy the traffic to a HTTP endpoint, which works, but this way I cannot get access to the request body and store it in dynamodb.

Since this task is at its core so easy I assume there is a simple way, but I can't seem to find a solution after a whole day of research. I'm open to any feedback and suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I think about enabling the following **Log full requests/responses data** feature of API Gateway stage.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html

From CWLogs, you will have a log group which stores those. You can create a **Metric Filter** to stream your logs to a supported destination, for example: Kinesis Firehose.

With Kinesis Firehose's data transformation, we can use a Lambda to unzip the data and store them to the DynamoDB.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html

But AWS has warned that this should not be used for production APIs because we log sensitive data I believe. But if you accept this, you can move forward with **HTTP proxy** integration if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Leondkr I tried out this setup and theoretically it works. Instead of using the data transformation lambda inside Kinesis Firehose, i send the request body to an HTTP Endpoint (AWS API Gateway) and use a lambda integration to store the data in dynamodb. However, this approach also has two main drawbacks: 1) The request body has a limit of 1024 bytes and if its longer this part simply gets truncated and is not accessible in cloudwatch at all. 2) API Gateway can only log the full request/response or nothing at all. This means that every request stores around 8kb of data to cloudwatch.

Comment: This results into similar costs as my first approach (lambdas sending the requests). Due to these 2 problems this solution is not really a good candidate for production purpose. If you have any other suggestions on how to tackle this problem, I would be happy to hear them :)